# Export CSV from JDE

Tags: csv, jdedwards

I need to import data from JD Edwards into MSSQL database. But I have some difficulty importing the CSV file (I'm using SSIS 2005).

In the CSV files, total 18 columns, but there are only 16 comma delimiters. By right with 18 columns, there should be 17 comma delimiters, but the comma delimiter for the last column (which all null) never been written to the CSV.

Does anyone ever encounter this and how to handle this?

Comment: A malformed CSV?  Horrors!  If it's a manual import you can fire up your text editor and add a comma to the end of each line.  A regular expression will take care of that in a second.

Answer (score 0):

hit another error from SSIS ([flat-file-parser-cannot-import-files-with-embedded-text-qualifiers](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/312164/flat-file-parser-cannot-import-files-with-embedded-text-qualifiers))
I finally use Log Parser 2.2 as workaround suggested, and it's working.